# Re-expressing equations

Tags: linear-algebra

$$Y =   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}D+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U$$
$$X =   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}D-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U$$
I have above two equations. I want to rewrite the above equations in terms of D and U in Mathematica. Is that possible?
After finding D and U equations in terms of X and Y, I am defining $$R=D+U$$. But the value of $R$ is not returning in terms of X and Y. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Assuming that you want to solve for `d` and `u`;  `Clear["Global\`*"];  eqns = {y == 1/Sqrt[2] (d + u), x == 1/Sqrt[2] (d - u)};  Solve[eqns, {d, u}][[1]] // Simplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon It’s working. But some errors are finding

Comment: Clear is where showing error

Comment: Try starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: If you'll always have nice linear systems of equations like this, linear algebra is your friend: `Inverse[1/Sqrt[2] {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}].{y, x} (* {x/Sqrt[2] + y/Sqrt[2], -(x/Sqrt[2]) + y/Sqrt[2]} *)`

Comment: I have edited the question. Is there a possibility to implement that?

Comment: If you have a third equation you can solve for a third variable. `Clear["Global\`*"]; eqns = {y == 1/Sqrt[2] (d + u), x == 1/Sqrt[2] (d - u), r == d + u}; Solve[eqns, {d, u, r}][[1]] // Simplify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll[d, u, x, y]
r = d + u /. 
   Solve[{y == d/Sqrt[2] + u/Sqrt[2], x == d/Sqrt[2] - u/Sqrt[2]}, {d, u}][[1]] // 
      FullSimplify
```

> ```
>  Sqrt[2] y
> ```

Alternatively, per b3m2a1's comment:

```
r = {1, 1}.Inverse[1/Sqrt[2] {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}].{y, x}
```

> ```
>  Sqrt[2] y
> ```